# Qt5: Qt Linguist redistributable

Tags: qt5, qt-linguist

I'm writing a manual for translators and can't find an easy and official way of Qt Linguist editor distribution. It looks like you can get it for Linux by downloading `qttools5-dev-tools` package. But for other systems?
Qt5 online installer doesn't seems to provide a separate Linguist component to download and I'm not sure if it's a part of QtCreator component. It's not feasible to force translators to install whole Qt framework bundle or even IDE to get it. I expected to find some Qt5 libraries redistributable+ Qt Linguist app + manuals in one package, but don't see any on qt.io.
Any recommendations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This site has standalone Qt Linguist installers for Windows & macOS

https://github.com/lelegard/qtlinguist-installers/releases

Comment: yep, I've ended up with this link too. Still, unfortunately, these copies aren't from official source and barely could be recommended in official document as well as need to be somehow verified against malware. But that's only feasible solution for now.

Comment: I've just found out that they finally make official Qt Linguist redistributable, Unfortunately, just for Win users: https://download.qt.io/linguist_releases/

Comment: The links on that page didn't work for me, but it was possible to access the Qt folder on one of the mirrors and download a Qt Linguist installer from there: http://mirrors.ukfast.co.uk/sites/qt.io/